# Shoot fireball once in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script for shooting fireballs from a cannon, but when clicking once the cannon shoot 3 or 4 balls! do you know guys how to shoot 1 ball per 1 click?

Here's my script:

```
public class CannonScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject CannonBall;
    public float FirePower;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Instantiate(CannonBall, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            CannonBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, 0, FirePower);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not be using FixedUpdate for any reason.  Some or much of Unity's early example code was basically insane, appalling, and that legacy lingers on.

Comment: @Fattie This is incorrect. `FixedUpdate()` is used when you need to do physics calculations. It makes sense because you don't want physics calculations to be tied to the framerate (as `Update()` is). See Unity's [`FixedUpdate` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Update()` for that, not `FixedUpdate()`. The truth is that [FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) should be strictly used for physics calculation, specifically when you are working with Rigidbodies.

Comment: The `Instantiate()` call should be in `Update()`, but the `AddForce()` call should be in `FixedUpdate()`.

Comment: @Andrea While this answer fixes OP's problem, I'm really curious why his CannonBall was instantiated 3/4 times in Fixed Update, do you have any explanation about that ?

Comment: @AntoineThiry as stated in the comments and in this answer, fixed update doesn't necessarily run every frame, the results of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` are based off the button was pressed that frame.  So depending on his Physic update loop (Which is editable in a setting) will depend on how often it is ran.  As an example a fixedupdate can run multiple times per frame, or it can run once every few frames.

Comment: @Eddge Thank you, this clarifies a lot for me :)

Comment: Thanks @Eddge, you anticipated me :) for curiosity, this is an interesting thread on Unity forum: https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-truth-about-fixedupdate.231637/